# Extract sub-element that not in every element in XML file using ElementTree Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I would like to extract data from XML file. But the problem is, the sub-element which I want (`portid`) is not in every element. When it loop in element I recieved error because it does not have the ('portid').

Below is my code to extract it:

```
def get_portid_in_registerFile(self): 
        for element_registerFile in self.crif_parser.getroot().findall('registerFile'):
            portid = element_registerFile.find('portid')
            print (portid.tag , ':', portid.text)
        return portid.tag
```

The output is:

```
 portid : 0x3A portid : 0x3A portid : 0x4E portid : 0x4E portid : 0x4E
 portid : 0x4F portid : 0x4F portid : 0x4F

 line 32, in get_portid_in_registerFile
     print (portid.tag , ':', portid.text) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

As shown above, the portid is shown when the element has portid. Then, it shows error when it loop in element that does not have the ('portid'). And do not continue looping.

May I know which part of the code that I need to change.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to post a representative portion of the xml.

Comment: post the xml please

Comment: Try changing `findall('registerFile')` to `findall('registerFile[portid]')`. Or maybe just add a try/except.

Comment: @DanielHaley it works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `findall('registerFile')` to `findall('registerFile[portid]')`.

Or maybe just add a try/except.